# Почему сообщения идут чат в чат?

Tags: php

iframe.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.location.reload()",10000);//Обновление раз в 5 секунд
</script>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
  $sql = "insert into `message` (`message`) values ('".$_POST['message']."')";
  mysql_query($sql);
}
$sql = "select `message` from `message` where 1 order by id desc";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
 printf("<div>%s</div>",$row->message);
}
?>
</body>
```

chat.php

```
<body>
<iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow' src='iframe.php'>Чатик</iframe>
<form action='chat.php' method='post' target='chatWindow'>
<input type='text' name='message'>
<input type='submit' />
</form> 
</body>
```

Где здесь есть ошибка? Сообщение не отправляет, отправляет чат в чат, как будто поставить зеркало напротив зеркала, что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В форме надо поменять action на "iframe.php", я же написал в комменте.

Comment: Ага спасибо)

Comment: Во работает ток сообщение не отправляет )

Comment: Влад, вы таблицу mysql создали?

Comment: Об этом вы ничего не говорили) ша создам) ток что в нее нужно вставить ?

Comment: Наверно пишет, что не может найти таблицу "messages"? *trollface*
Если все под денвером, заходим http://localhost/tools/phpmyadmin, там создаем новую базу данных, в ней создаем таблицу messages с полями id и message.

Затем в файле iframe.php пишем
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('ИМЯ_СОЗДАННОЙ_БАЗЫ',$connect);

Если и после этого не заработает - прошу полностью описание системы и что было/не было сделано

Comment: Это я знаю, спасибо большое)

Comment: Не не пашет таже ошибка